# PHP - items in array disappear

Tags: php, arrays, loops, items

I'm try to create a simple calendar and replace the hour by the event in the database, but only the first event show up, the other one are not display. I use a fetch_all and a loop to go through and convert the date to match the one in the table. When I do a var_dump after the loop, all the item appear, but when I do it in my if conditions only the first one is shown.

My code:

```
<tbody>
                        <?php
                        
                        for ($b = 0; isset($row[$b]); $b++) {
                            $event = date('d M Y H:i', strtotime($row[$b][1]));
                            while ($hour <= 19) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                for ($j = 0; $j <= 0; $j++) {
                                    $time1 = $hour . ":00";
                                    echo "<td>" . $time1 . "</td>";
                                }
                                for ($k = 0; isset($five_days[$k]); $k++) {
                                        $date_match = $five_days[$k].' '.$time1;
                                    if ($date_match === $event) {
                                        
                                        echo "<td>" . $row[$b][0]."</td>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<td>" . $time1 . "</td>";
                                    }
                                }
                                for ($j = 5; $j <= 6; $j++) {
                                    echo "<td>" . "Indisponible" . "</td>";
                                }
                                echo "</tr>";
                                $hour++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
```

I try to move the for loop who give me trouble, and when I do var_dump I get an array with a first date, another the first and second date, and a third one with all 3 date, but they all have the same a 0 index. Someone advised me to use DateTime instead of Date/strtotime, but it's a bit complicated to use for me.

Comment: for ($j = 0; $j <= 0; $j++) - 1. Initialize with 0. 2. Check if smaller or equal than null, true for the first run. 3. Increase j by 1. Condition false, for loop exiting

Comment: what is `for ($b = 0; isset($row[$b]); $b++) {`?  that is the same as `for(b=0;true|false;b++)` does not really make sense

Comment: for ($b = 0; isset($row[$b]); $b++) is the loop I use to go through the result of my database request.  for ($j = 0; $j <= 0; $j++) is the loop for the first columns that display the hours